On the multiplication of Block matrices
I am familiar with matrix multiplication $A_{n\times p} B_{p\times m} = C_{n\times m}$ where subscript in $A_{n \times p}$ says that the matrix $A$ has $n$ rows and $p$ columns, and similarly for $B$ and $C$. Now my question is related to Block matrix multiplication.
Now my question is how can one write the following sum
$$ \begin{pmatrix} A_{n\times n} & 0_{n \times n} \\0_{n \times n} & B_{n \times n} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} U_{n\times 1} \\  V_{n\times 1} \end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix} A_{n\times n}^\prime & 0_{n \times n} \\0_{n \times n} & B_{n \times n}^\prime \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} U_{n\times 1}^\prime \\  V_{n\times 1}^\prime \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ? \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} U_{n\times 1} \\ U_{n\times 1}^\prime \\ V_{n\times 1}\\  V_{n\times 1}^\prime \end{pmatrix} $$

I would think $\begin{pmatrix} AU+A'U' \BV+B'V' \end{pmatrix}$? Isn't that the point of this notation?

You can multiply block matrices the usual way, as long as the dimensions of the blocks match. You can convince yourself by playing with the expansion of the entries of the product matrix. For instance, if
\begin{align}
C_{m\times 2n}&=\begin{pmatrix}A_{m\times n} & B_{m\times n}\end{pmatrix} \\
Z_{2n\times 1}&=\begin{pmatrix}U_{n\times 1} \\ V_{n\times 1}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
[C_{m\times 2n} Z_{2n\times 1}]_{i,1} &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n} c_{i, k} z_{k,1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{i, k} z_{k,1} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} c_{i, k} z_{k,1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{i, k} u_{k,1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{i, k} v_{k,1} \\
&= [A_{m\times n} U_{n\times 1}]_{i,1} + [B_{m\times n} V_{n\times 1}]_{i,1}
\end{align}
which proves
$$
C_{m\times 2n} Z_{2n\times 1} = A_{m\times n} U_{n\times 1} + B_{m\times n} V_{n\times 1}.
$$
In your case
\begin{multline}
\begin{pmatrix}A_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & B_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}U_{n\times 1} \\ V_{n\times 1}\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}A'_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} \\ 0_{n\times n} & B'_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}U'_{n\times 1} \\ V'_{n\times 1}\end{pmatrix} \\
= \begin{pmatrix}A_{n\times n}U_{n\times 1} 
+ A'_{n\times n}U'_{n\times 1} \\ B_{n\times n}V_{n\times 1} + B'_{n\times n}V'_{n\times 1}\end{pmatrix} \\
=\begin{pmatrix}A_{n\times n} & A'_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n}\\ 0_{n\times n} & 0_{n\times n} & B_{n\times n}& B'_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}U_{n\times 1} \\ U'_{n\times 1} \\ V_{n\times 1} \\ V'_{n\times 1}\end{pmatrix}.
\end{multline}

$$ \begin{pmatrix} A_{n\times n} & 0_{n \times n} \\0_{n \times n} & B_{n \times n} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} U_{n\times 1} \\  V_{n\times 1} \end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix} A_{n\times n}^\prime & 0_{n \times n} \\0_{n \times n} & B_{n \times n}^\prime \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} U_{n\times 1}^\prime \\  V_{n\times 1}^\prime \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 
A_{n \times n} U_{n \times 1} + A_{n \times n}^\prime U_{n \times 1}^\prime \\ 
B_{n \times n} V_{n \times 1} + B_{n \times n}^\prime V_{n \times 1}^\prime 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
A_{n \times n} & A_{n \times n}^\prime & 0_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times n} \\ 
0_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times n} & B_{n \times n} & B_{n \times n}^\prime 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
U_{n \times 1} \\ 
U_{n \times 1}^\prime \\ 
V_{n \times 1} \\  
V_{n \times 1}^\prime 
\end{pmatrix}
 $$
